# How to delete any file with Terminal Ubuntu LTS 18.4.4

Tags: delete

I have tried to delete all files of "htdocs" of xampp local server. But did not complete this action.

please help me to complete this delete action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove all files you could use:

```
rm -r /somefolderpath/htdocs/*
```

Read about `rm` usage in its `man` page:

```
$ man rm
[...]
   -r, -R, --recursive
          remove directories and their contents recursively
[...]
```

If you've got `Permission denied` and you really know what you do, then use `sudo` to remove files and directories belonging to other user. This command will be executed with super user (root) permissions:

```
sudo rm -r /somefolder/htdocs/*
```